# JPA: better way to check if an entity has an association

Tags: java, jpa, associations, entity

Which is the better way to check if an entity has attached association?
I've a OneToOne association between Participant and Abstract entity and I want to know if a Participant has an abstract. For the moment I use the following code. Is there a better way?

```
public Long hasAbstract(String email) {
    Long absID;
    Participant p = find(email);
    try {
        return p.getAbstract_().getId();
    } catch (NullPointerException e){

    }
    return 0L;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using the exception handling to facilitate logic where possible. Instead just check if the object is null:

```
    public boolean hasAbstract(String email) {

         Participant p = find(email);
         return p.getAbstract_() == null ? 0L : p.getAbstract_().getId();
    }
```